# Grub on FreeBSD

Tags: grub, freebsd

I am new to FreeBSD world and currently using pfsense as a guest on Virtualbox. FreeBSD comes with default BTX bootloader. I want to replace it with Grub.

I tried running grub-install on /dev/ad1 or something grub complains of "Unable to mount partition" .

The root partition (slice) is ufs, I looked under /boot/grub and there is a ufs2 ( I hope it is backward compatible ) module for grub, but still no luck.

Has anyone has ever tried similar scenario.

Comment: First question that comes to mind: Why would you want to do that? All Grub does in that scenario is load the FreeBSD Boot loader, which then loads FreeBSD.
The only scenario where a Grub in front of FreeBSDs own loader would seem to make sense is a multiboot, and since I take from your post that your FreeBSD is running within VirtualBox I don't see that happening. So allow me this question: What are you trying to achieve and why?

Answer (score 2):

I have just successfully done just this.

Here's how:

```
# cd /usr/ports/sysutils/grub
# make install
... make commences ...
# sysctl kern.geom.debugflags=16
kern.geom.debugflags: 0 -> 16
# /usr/local/sbin/grub-install
# reboot
```

That left me at the grub> prompt at which I issued:

```
grub> kernel /boot/loader
... loader loads ...
grub> boot
```

And I am into FreeBSD>

The latter part should be done through the grub configuration file.

By the looks of things it was the `sysctl` line you may have missed out.  This turns on the ability to write to the hard drive's system areas which is denied by default.

***Addendum***

**Setting up a simple boot menu:**

Add the following to the file /boot/grub/menu.lst:

```
title FreeBSD
root (hd0,a)
kernel /boot/loader
```

and you will get a simple boot menu with one entry in it for FreeBSD.